# Moving nodes of different multipolygon on different layers

Tags: layers, nodes

I would like to import into Openstreetmap the land-use data. In order to do a good job, I would like to correct some imperfections before the import. Take a look at this screenshot (which is a small area of the current project):

[image: Screenshot of the project]

The two green regions represent two different adjoining towns. Each multipolygon indicates a land use. The red lines are main roads, tracks, paths, water streams. It is simple to recognize main roads, since these separates the land-use with a white space.

Unfortunately, in the picture you can see the main road is going to cross the separation regions on multiple occasions. The main roads are accurately mapped with GPS devices, while the land-use data has been built by local administrations knowledge and aerial imaginery: this explains the crossing.

I would really like to solve all these crossing before the import. Given my limited experience with QGIS, the only solution I can see is to manually move all the different nodes of the different multipolygon and the different layers (with the help of the snap options): this is simply unacceptable given the tremendous amount of time it would take.

Do you know any other possible approach? Is there any plugin that could help me achive my goal?